# Schoenfield residual test for discrete-time hazard model in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have modeled a discrete-time hazard model using the following code:

```
(logit.full. <-
   glmer(event ~ 
              + a1
              + a2
              + a3
              + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3
              + (1 + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3 | country_cluster),
     family=binomial("logit"), data=data.final))
```

Now I would like to test this model for the proportionality assumption that is inheritet in these types of discrete-time hazard models.

For continous time hazard models (Cox models), this is tested with the Schoenfield residual test.  In R, this test is executed with "cox.zph" command which is part of the "survival" package.

Does anyone know any possibility to excecute this test for my discrete-time hazard model in R?

Comment: This is a cross-validated post